# Turn a List of digits into an Intenger in C

Tags: c

Given a list of digits, for example:  <1 6 3 2 5>
How can you turn it into an integer?
In this case, 16325.
I was able do the reverse operation, turning an integer into a list of digits, but im stuck with this one...

Comment: 1 times the last, 10 times the second last, 100 times third last, etc.

Comment: @nicknickC Just keep a copy of the original number when you are splitting it into digits.:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short program that takes an integer array and multiplies it out into an integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int output = 0;
    int numbers[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int size = sizeof numbers / sizeof numbers[0];
    
    for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
    {
        output = output + numbers[size-i] * pow(10,i-1); 
        printf("%d\n",output);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

First, it finds the length of the array. Then it needs take each element and multiply it by a power of ten depending upon its location in the array, adding to output to get the total sum.

Comment: Iterating over the numbers from left to right is much easier, and you don't need to use `pow` from `math.h`: `output = 10 * output + numbers[i];`

Comment: Not to mention `pow()` returning type `double`.

Comment: I like the `size`, but also, the number `[5]` could have been `[]`.